# How to forecast time series analysis for more then one dependent variables?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have three datasets:

Dataset_1= column name as `ID, Date, counter_id`

Dataset_2= column name as `ID, no. of tickets sold`

Dataset_3= column names as `ID, country_code`.

Here, `country_code` ranges from 1 to 30 as codes for different countries and `counter_id` as counter codes ranging from 1 to 100. I merged the datasets based on common column `ID`.

I have to estimate how many tickets will be sold during the next 20 days in a given country and through a specific counter.

What I have done is predict the number of tickets sold for next 10 days using time series forecasting. But, I'm not able to decide how I can predict the `counter_id` and `country_code` along with tickets sold? Please give me some useful feedback. I am a beginner in data science. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need to "predict" *counter_id* and *country_code* as variables, what you need is to produce results to every counter and country (and sometimes these results will be zero).

The technique you are looking for is called **VAR (Vector Autoregression)**

[VAR](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/16-1-vector-autoregressions.html)

The vector autoregression (VAR) model is one of the most successful, flexible, and easy to use models for the analysis of multivariate time series. It is a natural extension of the univariate autoregressive model to dynamic multivariate time series.

The equation you propose is solvable by VAR:

$Y_t = C + A_1 Y_{t-1} + A_2 Y_{t-2} + ... + A_n Y_{t-n}$

Where $Y_t = \begin{bmatrix} Y_{i=1,j=1,t} \\ Y_{i=1,j=2,t} \\
\vdots \\
Y_{i=1,j=m,t} \\
\vdots \\
Y_{i=n,j=m,t} \end{bmatrix}$

Where, $i$ is every country, $j$ is every counter.

The usage is very similar to univariate time series analysis, which you are probably familiar with.